# Core Data cannot fulfill a fault when I tried to save

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode5

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for

At first I thought that it's because the object I want to update has the wrong NSManagedObjectContext

So before that I did:

```
    for (NSManagedObject * mo in moc.updatedObjects.allObjects) {
        [mo assertNSManagedObjectisHealthy];
    }

-(void) assertNSManagedObjectisHealthy
{
    //AssertMainThread;
    NSManagedObjectContext * moc = [BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectContext *mocObject=self.managedObjectContext;
    NSAssert (moc==mocObject,@"Something is wrong why moc is not the same");
}
```

Then the error actually happen here:

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    @synchronized([BGFetchClass class])
    {
        saveSuccesfully = [moc save:&error]; //Error here
        if (!saveSuccesfully) {
            CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);
        }
        else{
        }
    }
}];
```